# A yielded value of type 'Stream<LocationData>' must be assignable to 'LocationData'

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to make a stream function that returns `LocationData` as stream.
But I got this error saying

`A yielded value of type 'Stream<LocationData>' must be assignable to 'LocationData'`

```
Stream<LocationData>  getCoordinates() async* {
      yield Location.instance.onLocationChanged;//error shows here
}
```

Comment: Kindly share code where you receiving the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your error message, you are missing a `*` after your `yield` to actually yield each item in your stream:

```
Stream<LocationData>  getCoordinates() async* {
      yield* Location.instance.onLocationChanged;
}
```

Please note that this is an educated guess, next time it would really help to have more code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe This helps anyone who needs to return a stream of data so I think you have to provide something like this

If you want to return a stream of data inside a listener which return another stream of data maybe you can do something like this.

```
  Stream<LocationData> getUserLiveLocation() async* {
   yield* location.onLocationChanged;
```

}